# How can I save my reading postion in the "less" terminal app?

Tags: command-line, vim, less

just trying to learn what I can and cannot do with this application if this is not possible are there any terminal reading apps that will allow such a thing? or maybe a script that can help?

Comment: Did you read `man less`, the definitive manual on what you can accomplish with that software?

Comment: If you invoke `less` with the `--save-marks` option (for example, by exporting `LESS="--save-marks"` in your environment) then you can use the `m` or `M` (*mark*) commands to save a position between sessions

Comment: @user535733 I'm a noob when it comes to terminals ill make sure to do this in the future.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks!